# count number of foreign keys

Tags: mysql

i have three tables.

**1.`fi_category`**

```
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
| id | name            | slug            |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
```

**2.`fi_subcategory`**

```
+----+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+
| id | name            | slug            | category_id |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

**3.`fi_business_subcategory`**

```
+----+-------------+----------------+
| id | business_id | subcategory_id |
+----+-------------+----------------+
```

what i am basically trying to do is,

1. fetch all categories
2. fetch all subcategories that belong to categories.
3. count the number of business that exist for particular subcategory.

this is what i tried doing.

```
SELECT 
    f.id,
    f.name,
    f.slug,
    f2.id,
    f2.name,
    f2.slug,
    COUNT(f3.business_id) as count
FROM
    fi_category f
LEFT JOIN 
    fi_subcategory f2 ON f.id = f2.category_id
LEFT JOIN 
    fi_business_subcategory f3 ON f2.id = f3.subcategory_id
```

however the above query fetches only 1 record. how do i fetch what i want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT 
    f.id,
    f.name,
    f.slug,
    f2.id,
    f2.name,
    f2.slug,
    COUNT(f3.business_id) as count
FROM fi_category f
LEFT JOIN fi_subcategory f2 
    ON f.id = f2.category_id
LEFT JOIN fi_business_subcategory f3 
    ON f2.id = f3.subcategory_id
GROUP BY f.id,
    f.name,
    f.slug,
    f2.id,
    f2.name,
    f2.slug
```

Or get your `count()` in a sub-query:

```
SELECT f.id,
    f.name,
    f.slug,
    f2.id,
    f2.name,
    f2.slug,
    f3.cnt
FROM fi_category f
LEFT JOIN fi_subcategory f2 
    ON f.id = f2.category_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    select count(business_id) cnt, subcategory_id 
    from fi_business_subcategory
    group by subcategory_id
) f3 
    ON f2.id = f3.subcategory_id
```