# count number of foreign key in doctrine

Tags: doctrine, dql

This is follow up of this question: [count number of foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371304/count-number-of-foreign-keys)

I am using doctrine 1.2 and I want to count the number of business that belongs to subcategory.

Following are the mysql tables.

**1.`fi_category`**

```
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
| id | name            | slug            |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+
```

**2.`fi_subcategory`**

```
+----+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+
| id | name            | slug            | category_id |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

**3.`fi_business_subcategory`**

```
+----+-------------+----------------+
| id | business_id | subcategory_id |
+----+-------------+----------------+
```

I am using this DQL.

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('c.name, c.slug, sc.name, sc.slug')
    ->from('Model_Category c')
    ->leftJoin('c.Subcategory sc')
    ->leftJoin('sc.BusinessSubcategory bsc');
```

which gives me something like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Entertainment & Lifestyle
        [slug] => entertainment-lifestyle
        [Subcategory] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => Arts and Crafts
                [slug] => arts-and-crafts
            )
            [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => Family
                [slug] => family
            )
            [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [name] => Fashion
                [slug] => fashion
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I am looking to fetch the number of business, i.e the returned result should be something like this depending on the business it belongs.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Entertainment & Lifestyle
        [slug] => entertainment-lifestyle
        [Subcategory] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => Arts and Crafts
                [slug] => arts-and-crafts
                [business_count] => 35
            )
            [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => Family
                [slug] => family
                [business_count] => 10
            )
            [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [name] => Fashion
                [slug] => fashion
                [business_count] => 27
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Tried various ways using DQL, but nothing seems to work out. Any idea how should I go with what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
     ->select('c.name, c.slug, sc.name, sc.slug, COUNT(sc.BusinessSubcategory.id) AS business_count')
     ->from('Model_Category c')
     ->leftJoin('c.Subcategory sc')
     ->groupBy('c.id, sc.id');
```

with `HYDRATE_ARRAY`

Comment: this works, thank you so much, never knew DQL allows you to do this kind of queries. :)